# Question about updating my angular project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to update my angular project but I'm having some issues.
It shows me the following  message:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (8.0.1) is greater than your local
version (1.7.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

Error: Cannot update safely because packages have conflicting dependencies. Package @angular/core would need to match both versions "7.2.15" and "8.0.0, which are not compatible.
Cannot update safely because packages have conflicting dependencies. Package @angular/core would need to match both versions "7.2.15" and "8.0.0, which are not compatible.
```

If anyone could help me ?

Comment: Please add your `package.json` file to the question.

Comment: This discussion helped me to find solution https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14581

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to upgrading your Angular project in general, simply run this:

```
ng update
```

Otherwise, if you want to perform an upgrade on just the CLI, you can the specific package as an option

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

Or directly install via `npm`

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli
```

If you need to do a hard reset, you can first install the CLI globally, followed by updating the one in your project itself.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Then, you `cd` to our project directory,

```
rm -rf node_modules dist 
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm i 
ng update @angular/cli 
ng update @angular/core
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Comment: When I try to update @angular/cli, it shows me that message, and I can't update my project

Comment: @RicardoGraciano I have another one. Let me update my answer now.